# How can I detect a fling gesture when there are widgets involved?

Tags: android, android-event

Background: I'm trying to detect edge swipes in my app (to bring up a menu), and searching stackoverflow seems to indicate that the way to detect swipes is to start with fling detection.

I'm trying to detect a fling event in my app. I can override `dispatchTouchEvent()` or `onTouchEvent()` and pass the event to a gesture listener and everything works as you would expect.

However, my app has button widgets in it and I can't both detect the fling and use the widgets.

If I call the gesture detector from `onTouchEvent()`, flings are not detected if the gesture starts over a widget that consumes the event. If I call the gesture detector from `dispatchTouchEvent()`, the widgets don't get the events they need.

I've also tried attaching to the container's `onTouchEvent()` but the result was the same.

Finally, I've looked at the source code to ViewPager to see how they do it, and what they do is override `onInterceptTouchEvent()`. I can see how and why this works, but I was hoping there was a simpler solution that didn't require me to implement my own container widget.

Source code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Fling extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "FlingTest";

    protected GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, listener);
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    */

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final SimpleOnGestureListener listener =
      new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e1) { return true; }
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vx, float vy) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fling: " + vx + "," + vy);
            return true;
        }
      };
}
```

The layout.xml file, although pretty much any layout will show these issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPane"
    android:background="#446"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    <Button
        android:text="btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    <Button
        android:text="btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I found one answer that comes pretty close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection. It requires that you attach the gesture listener to every single view in the activity. I have a *lot* of views, but maybe it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one answer that seems to work. I change dispatchTouchEvent() to *both* call the gesture detector *and* pass the event up the chain.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

It's not pretty, and I'm not sure it's robust, but it seems to work.

Still hoping for a better answer, but I think I'll give this method a try.